# java - basic web app not working with jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey

My web.xml file

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.pack.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My class

```
  package com.pack.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/version")
public class Version {

    private static final String VERSION="1.0.0";


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public static String getVersion() {
        return VERSION;
    }

}
```

When I run the project with tomcat it takes me to
http://localhost:8080/LeaderboardService/

I can see a Hello World.

If i go to
http://localhost:8080/LeaderboardService/api/version I get 404.
Why?

**Edit 1**
Removed static from the method

My class:

```
  package com.boldijarpaul.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/version")
public class Version {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getVersion() {
        return "hello stackoverflow";
    }

}
```

But after I restart tomcat and run the project 
[image]

And when I want to call my API
[image]

My project structure,maybe here is the problem?

[image]

I've also tried to manually deploy to apache, by copying the .war file inside the webapp. Same thing
War file - https://www.sendspace.com/file/4cd4m0

Comment: Did u tried to declare the getVersion() as object level method?

Answer (score 1):

As it was told in the comment, your rest method must not be static. The instance of the Rest object is managed by Jersey at runtime.

Take off the static keyword from the getVersion() method.

Comment: Maybe you should use a more recent dependency if Jersey. As you can see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/jax-rs.html#d4e186), you need to declare your Endpoint (REST class) in an application class or in the web.xml for Jersey 1.x. If you want your Endpoints to be detected automatically migrate to [Jersey 2.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html). In your Maven file change org.sun.jersey dependencies for [org.glassfish.jersey](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server). Tell me if you're OK with it I'll edit the answer

Comment: I've deleted this project and copied one from the internet, changed all the packages and now everything works.. I still can't figure out what was the problem, i was creating the project with Spring Tool Suite - New Dynamic Web Project...anyways, thanks for your help!